# Chrome Emulator not activating media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, html-email, viewport, meta-tags

I'm building a HTML email and have been using Chrome emulator to test the responsive states but now the emulator isn't triggering the media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

Any thoughts?

I've tried restarting multiple times and the emulator works fine on other sites. Attached is a screenshot showing what happens when i select the "body" element in Console.

[image: screenshot showing what happens when i select the "body" element in Console]

EDIT
The problem is due to removing the viewport meta tag, yet this is advised to be removed from responsive emails... Anyone know a solution for this?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the emulator, it's pretty inaccurate in my experience.

Comment: I find the emulator a bit of a pain. Do you have the meta tag in the head of the document? Silly question I know. I found that Firefox Developer extension allows you to set all sorts of device widths and you can test your MQ's in there. Not sure how helpful that is :)

Comment: @mattytommo we run device testing on EOA too but emulator helps debug a bit, or used to!

Comment: @DeanWhitehouse I simply resize the browser when I'm debugging, that seems more reliable!!

Comment: @mattytommo that's not working either! Trying Safari remote inspector now

Comment: Can you post some markup? Are you using table layout? I just checked here, and they are setting max width for the inner content which means it will scale down on resize: http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-email-templates/hero.html and this is the meta tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: @lharby wish I could but it's a bespoke build under NDA so a blurry screenshot and excerpts are all I can provided. Looked at Zurb but we're having to build to a strict design so couldn't use the column system :/ Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Why are you removing the meta tag? You can leave it. Some email clients will remove the `head` of your content, but you don't need to remove that tag yourself. For instance, Zurb ink has a meta tag in their own templates: http://zurb.com/ink/downloads/templates/basic.html

Comment: You said you've tried restarting, which I assume means closing chrome and reopening, but have you tried refreshing the page while still in the emulator view?  I've found that issue to happen on some sites I've worked on until I've refreshed with the page already in emulator mode.

Comment: You could strip out the content code and just add the skeleton in a jsfiddle? I mean the most basic structure.

Comment: Have you tried max-width instead of max-device-width? If that doesn't work, I found one workaround is in Chrome dev tools, go to the emulation panel (part of the "drawer" tools along with console), and un-check "Emulate Mobile".

Answer (score 0):

Try using max-width. Chrome emulator shows responsive email correctly on my Chrome and I use it on all my templates.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

`max-width` is better than `max-device-width` because of multiple reasons. Primary one is that to trigger certain Android phones, if you used `max-device-width`, you had to set it to horizontal resolution (1920px on some phones on landscape!), while `max-width` had to be set to viewport width (which is around 480px). On iPhone both are the same last time I checked.

It is best practice to use `max-width` in email media queries.

Also, you don't have to put `480px`, I tend to set higher values, either `580px` or 1px less than outer container width.